# Is there any nonabelian group of order $n$ that isn't a subgroup of $S_{n-1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

As far as I know, the only groups of order $n$ that aren't subgroups of $S_{n-1}$ are cyclic groups with prime power order and the Klein four-group. Is there any nonabelian group of order $n$ that isn't a subgroup of $S_{n-1}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597347/finding-the-minimal-n-such-that-a-given-finite-group-g-is-a-subgroup-of-s-n

Comment: Yes. In particular for $n=8$, the quaternion group $Q_8$ is not isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_7$ - see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481957/q-8-is-isomorphic-to-a-subgroup-of-s-8-but-not-isomorphic-to-a-subgroup-of?rq=1).